# How to restore the farm Backup?

Tags: sharepoint-server, powershell, central-administration

I need to Restore the farm backup in  SharePoint 2013,So please share the steps for restoring process.

Comment: give us more details, what you want to restore and what kind of Backup you have etc?

Answer (score 1):

Provided that you have a valid backup, this is what you do.

Get the BackupId use

```
$BackupID = Get-SPBackupHistory -Directory "D:\Backup\" -ShowBackup
```

Then restore your farm, like this:

```
Restore-SPFarm -Directory "D:\Backup\" -RestoreMethod Overwrite -BackupId $BackupID
```

When this is done you need to start the service instance(s)

```
Start-SPServiceInstance -Identity <ServiceApplicationID>
```

Source: [Restore farms in SharePoint 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee428314.aspx#PS)